# Toolbar is hiding on Scroll upward in listView but don't come back when scrolled downward

Tags: javascript, android, fragment, toolbar, onscroll

In my app i am using the design toolbar. In one activity i am using list view which fetches data from a json and show it. When the user scroll upward the toolbar hides but when user scroll back down the toolbar don't come back. This is my code.

```
public class QA_Activity extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = QA_Activity.class.getSimpleName();
    private ListView listView;
    private QAFeedListAdapter listAdapter;
    private List<QAFeedItem> feedItems;
    private String URL_FEED = "http://localhost/quesans.json";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_activity, container, false);

        listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list);


        feedItems = new ArrayList<QAFeedItem>();

        listAdapter = new QAFeedListAdapter(getActivity(), feedItems);
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

            listView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
                private int mLast;

                public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

                }

                public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                        int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

                    if (mLast < firstVisibleItem) {
                        if (((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().isShowing()) {
                            ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();
                        }
                    }
                    if (mLast > firstVisibleItem) {
                        if (((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().isShowing()) {
                            ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().show();
                        }
                    }
                    mLast = firstVisibleItem;
                }
            });

            JsonObjectRequest jsonReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET,
                    URL_FEED, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Response: " + response.toString());
                            if (response != null) {
                                parseJsonFeed(response);
                            }
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                        }
                    });

            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonReq);
            return v;
        }

    private void parseJsonFeed(JSONObject response) {
        try {
            JSONArray feedArray = response.getJSONArray("questionanswer");

            for (int i = 0; i < feedArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject feedObj = (JSONObject) feedArray.get(i);

                QAFeedItem item = new QAFeedItem();
                item.setId(feedObj.getInt("id"));
                item.setName(feedObj.getString("question"));
                item.setStatus(feedObj.getString("answer"));

                feedItems.add(item);
            }

            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

What i want is when the user scroll down the toolbar should show up.

Answer (score 0):

You can do is

**UPDATE**

Create a layout for the toolbar
layout/your_toolbar_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/your_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And inflate the toolbar layout

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_toolbar_layout, null);
Toolbar toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.your_toolbar); //your reference to the toolbar

listView.addHeaderView(view)
```

Comment: I am getting this error now `The method addHeaderView(View) in the type ListView is not applicable for the arguments (int)`

Comment: Are you putting the id?

Comment: Yes i am putting the id

Comment: Now my app crashes and i am getting this error `E/AndroidRuntime(10366): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot add header view to list -- setAdapter has already been called.
`

Comment: Opps sorry, check again my updated answer, because the view is already on the XML. You can make a toolbar layout and inflate it and add it to the listview

Comment: Updated again my answer, sorry for many trial and error. I'm not on my pc as of now. I think it will work this time

Comment: Its not working. Although its not crashing now but parsing of json has also stoped and now i am getting a blank activity and toolbar is not hiding/showing

Answer (score 0):

Are you Looking for something like this?

[image: collapsing toolbar]

If so, you can use design support library elements like `CoordinatorLayout` and `AppBarLayout`.

For more details, refer to this [tutorial](http://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout#floating-action-buttons-and-snackbars).